# Map (hashmap) with inner Map (3 values)

Tags: java, entity-framework, hashmap

I would like to create an object with `Map<String,Map<Integer, String>>` the inner should not be a Map type because the inner key (Integer) is not a primary key (unique). And as far as I know when it comes to Map if there is a similar key value it will override the previous similar data.

What should be the datatype of my inner Map?

Comment: `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<String>>>`

Comment: Map<String, Multimap<Integer, String>> - (https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: Have a look at Guava's [Multimap](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

Comment: I am restricted to use additional imports due to policy

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are going to do with the map. If the values of the outer map are just pairs, you can use `Map<String, Set<ClassContainingIntAndString>>`, or if you already know what it is (like you said there are only three values?) `Map<String, SomeClassThatMakesSense>`. However, if you want fast access to the final Strings given the first and second Integer, you should use `Map<String, Map<Integer, List<String>>>` (or something similar except encapsulated in some user-defined classes, as it may be bad practice to have too many nested generics).

Comment: The first option might work, Map<String, Map<Integer, List<String>>> I can do this because the inner map key is not unique